# Convert python list to polars dataframe

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a list and a variable, eg:

```
myvar = 'KEY_1'
mylist = ['apple', 'banana', 'peach']
```

I'd like to convert them to a Polars dataframe of something like:

```
PROD   PARAM1 PARAM2 PARAM3
KEY_1  apple  banana peach
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be:

```
import polars as pl

myvar = 'KEY_1'
mylist = ['apple', 'banana', 'peach']

keys = ['PARAM'+str(e+1) for e,i in enumerate(mylist)]
keys.append('PRODUCT')
mylist.append(myvar)

pl.from_dict(dict(zip(keys, mylist)))
```

Comment: Incase it may be useful, some other possible ways: 1) `pl.DataFrame({"PARAM": mylist}).unstack(1).select(pl.lit(myvar).alias("PRODUCT"), pl.all())` 2) `pl.DataFrame({"PARAM": [myvar] + mylist}).unstack(1).rename({"PARAM_0": "PRODUCT"})`